Recursive quadratic equation and sum of the maximum solution
The positive real numbers $x_0,x_1...x_m$ satisfy $x_0=x_m$ and $x_{i−1}+\frac{k}{x_{i−1}}=kx_i+\frac{1}{x_i}$
Let $x_0(k,m)$ be its maximum possible value of $x_0$.
If ($k=2$ and $m=59$), find the summation of such $x_0(k,m)$ when you increase $k$ by $1$ and at the same time decrease $m$ by $2$ till both become equal.
My attempt:
I got $x_i = \frac{x_{i-1}}{k} \text{ or } \frac{1}{x_{i-1}}.$
So,
\begin{align}
x_1 &= \frac{x_0}{k} \text{ or } \frac{1}{x_0} \notag \\
x_2 &= \frac{x_0}{k^2} \text{ or } \frac{1}{kx_0} \text{ or } \frac{k}{x_0} \text{ or } x_0\notag \\
\vdots & \notag \\
\end{align}
Like this, we can get many possible values of $x_m$ right?
But how to decide the sequence of operations which gives the maximum value of $x_0$?
(EDIT: I misunderstood that $x_i = \frac{x_{i-1}}{k} \text{ or } \frac{1}{x_{i-1}}$ means only one condition (that is fixed) of the two satisfies everytime. @CalvinLin has helped me to understand this. )

1/ Please edit the post to state the full problem on this site. $\quad$ 2/ The condition that $x_i = x_{i-1}/k$ or $1/x_{i-1}$ holds for each $i$. It doesn't mean that for each $i$ we must choose the same branch. For example, we could have $x_2 = x_1/k, x_3 = 1/x_2$.

I have edited the question.

Hint: $x_i = k^ f(i) x_0 ^ \pm 1$. Determine what values $f(i)$ can hold, and hence what the maximum $x_i$ could be.

Note that the possible values of $x_m$ are
$$
\{ k^{-m+n}x_0^{(-1)^n}: n=0,1,\ldots,2m-1\}.
$$
Let’s prove it using induction. This is true for $m=1$ as shown by the OP. Say it’s true for $m$. Then the possible values for $x_{m+1}$ are
\begin{align}
&\{ k^{-m-1+n}x_0^{(-1)^n}: n=0,1,\ldots,2m-1\} \cup \{ k^{m-n}x_0^{-(-1)^n}: n=0,1,\ldots,2m-1\}
\\
&= \{ k^{-m-1+n}x_0^{(-1)^n}: n=0,1,\ldots,2m-1\} \cup \{ k^{-m-1+n’}x_0^{(-1)^{n’}}: n’=2,3,\ldots,2m+1\}
\\
&= \{ k^{-m-1+n}x_0^{(-1)^n}: n=0,1,\ldots,2m+1\},
\end{align}
where I defined $n’=2m+1-n$.

Now let’s consider $m$ odd and $k>1$, since that’s the case in the problem. We need
$$
x_0 = x_m = k^{-m+n}x_0^{(-1)^n},
$$
for some $n=0,1,\ldots,2m-1$. Since $x_0$ is a positive real number, there is no solution with $n$ even. For $n$ odd, we get
$$
x_0 = k^{(n-m)/2}.
$$
So, the maximum value
$$
x_0(k,m) = k^{(m-1)/2},
$$
is achieved for $n= 2m-1$. Hence, the required sum is
$$
2^{29}+3^{28}+4^{27}+\cdots+21^{10}.
$$
I’m not sure if there’s a simpler representation of this sum.

Thanks for the solution! But how did you get the idea of expressing the possible values of $x_m$ in a closed form?

@NagaSaiPrajith I extrapolated what you wrote for $x_1$ and $x_2$. I noticed that both the smallest and the largest powers of $k$ come from the smallest power of $k$ of the previous set.
